# Sum of Two Fields in Alv Report and Display Total in Third Field

Tags: abap, alv

How to sum the fields amount and tax and display total in third field in alv report?

Table and fields are:

vbak-netwr

vbap-mwsbp

Comment: If you are not trying to update those fields, just add a third field to your table, do the sums before the display and voilà.

Comment: thanks.. do you have any refference code..

Comment: What you've tried so far? Post the code.

Comment: Can you describe more specifically what problem you face when implementing that logic?
Your questions is too broad and the answer would be a full solution ( maybe 200 lines of code) + a guide on how to use ALV grids.
What do you need help with? SQL, abap syntax, ALV grind implementation?

Comment: There is no need of reference code if you know any small bit about ABAP. I pressumed you have enough code to fill the table and show it without the sum field, and just told you to add a field, make the sum and show it.

Comment: I found the solution.. forgot to add fieldcatelog entry of sum :p.. now its done.. thanks for your help everyone..

Answer (score 0):

Firt of all, you need Fill the work_area of table fieldcat and after that you need APPEND work_area-fieldcat TO it_fieldcat, you need do it for all fields in your out internal table , When you want a sum in some field, you use wa_fieldcat-sum 'X'.
Examples:

```
wa_fieldcat-fieldname     =     'NETWR'.     "Name of field.
wa_fieldcat-tabname       =     'IT_VBAK'.   "Name of Internal Table.
wa_fieldcat-ref_fieldname =     'NETWR'.     "Reference of field
wa_fieldcat-ref_tabname   =     'VBAK'.      "Reference of Table
wa_fieldcat-sum           =     'X'.         "Making a sum of Field
```

Comment: actually I want to sum two field values and display the total in third field eg. 100|100|200.

Comment: Ow, Okay! then you need a other field in your internal table, this field will the sum of netwr + mwsbp, you can do it in processing datas, when you going to fill the out internal table.

Comment: ok i am closing this discussion.. I found the solution.. forgot to add fieldcatelog entry of sum :p.. now its done..  thanks for your help everyone...